# Merge data.table returns empty variable - R

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have two `data.tables` which I'm trying to merge. However, these rows in these `data.tables` need a large number of variables to avoid duplicates. Due to confidentiality data we don't have identifier variables and I need a conjunction of several variables to match these two datasets.

I tried to join them however once I look at the final dataset the variable is empty. All the values are set to NULL. `data1` has 17440 observations and 57 variables. `old_data` has 17347 observations and 12 variables. I need 11 variables to get unique observations, let's name them `key_variables`. Here's what I have:

```
key_variables <- c("sex", "birthdate", "sint", "cons", "diag", "concelho", "Serologia", "alcohol", "end", "micro")

setkeyv(data1, key_variables)
setkeyv(old_data, key_variables)

dataFinal <- merge(data1, old_data, key_variables, all.x = T)
```

The variable I'm trying to add to `data1` is a factor. I tried to change to character but I still get the variable set to NULL. Any idea of what could be causing this issue?

```
str(old_data)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  17347 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ sex            : Factor w/ 2 levels "Male","Female": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "llevels")= int  1 2
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Sex"
 $ birthdate      : labelled, format: NA NA ...
 $ diagnosis_date : labelled, format: "2009-01-09" "2009-10-15" ...
 $ county         : Factor w/ 300 levels "Lisboa","Sines",..: 23 62 244 34 18 37 1 27 60 66 ...
  ..- attr(*, "llevels")= int  11 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "County"

str(data)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  17440 obs. of  57 variables:
  $ ID               : chr  "12083" "12084" "12087" "12096" ...
  $ sex              : Factor w/ 2 levels "Male","Female": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
   ..- attr(*, "llevels")= int  1 2
  $ birthdate        : Date, format: NA NA ...
  $ county           : Factor w/ 300 levels "Lisboa","Sines",..: 17 17 50 235 25 84 28 1 20 47 ...
   ..- attr(*, "llevels")= int  10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ..


dput(data1)
structure(list(sex = c("Masculino", "Masculino", "Masculino"), 
birthdate = c("4/23/1952", "11/26/1964", "01/08/1965"), sint = c("01/01/2014", 
"09/01/2010", "01/01/2008"), cons = c("02/10/2014", "12/01/2010", 
"1/29/2008"), diag = c("02/10/2014", "12/03/2010", "02/03/2008"
), concelho = c("vila velha de ródão", "vila velha de ródão", 
"vila velha de ródão"), Serologia = c("Não", "Não", "Não"
), alcohol = c("Sim", "Não", "Sim"), end = c("11/03/2014", 
"10/10/2011", "9/17/2008"), micro = c("03/11/2008", "12/03/2010", 
"02/03/2008"), DInflamatoriaArticular = c("Não", "Não", "Não"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001f2af621ef0>)

dput(old_data)
structure(list(sex = c("Masculino", "Masculino", "Masculino"), 
birthdate = c("23/04/1952", "26/11/1964", "08/01/1965"), 
age = c(61L, 46L, 43L), concelho = c("vila velha de ródão", 
"vila velha de ródão", "vila velha de ródão"), EstadoVital = c("Vivo", 
"Vivo", "Vivo"), sint = c("01/01/2014", "01/09/2010", "01/01/2008"
), cons = c("10/02/2014", "01/12/2010", "29/01/2008"), alcohol = c("Sim", 
"Não", "Sim"), drugs = c("Não", "Não", "Não"), micro = c("11/03/2008", 
"03/12/2010", "03/02/2008"), diag = c("10/02/2014", "03/12/2010", 
"03/02/2008"), Serologia = c("Não", "Não", "Não"), end = c("03/11/2014", 
"10/10/2011", "17/09/2008"), Motivotermotratamento = c("Tratamento Completado", 
"Tratamento Completado", "Tratamento Completado"), ano = c(2014L, 
2010L, 2008L), region = c("Centro", "Centro", "Centro")), row.names = c(NA,-3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001f2af621ef0>)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the content of the `key_variables` of both `data.table`s are matching? I'd check with e.g.: `unique(data1[[key_variables[1]]]) %in% unique(old_data[[key_variables[1]]])`. Maybe there is a small difference in the content preventing the join?

Comment: Yes, the output is TRUE TRUE. I was comparing the data.tables and one difference would be the labels. One data.table has variable labels and another don't. I wouldn't imagine why that would be an issue though..

Comment: Is it `TRUE` for all `key_variables`? Do you have the possibility to create a dummy dataset to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I added the structure of the data.tables. `old_data` has an attribute which is the variable label. Now that I'm looking at the structures side by side, the problem could be differences in factor levels, right? `county` has 300 levels, if the levels don't match there's no merge?

Comment: Yes, I guess you have to align the structure of your factor variables.

Comment: Hi, so it's still not working and it's probably something basic. So I have a small example: this would be `data1` http://www.filedropper.com/newfile and this `old_data` http://www.filedropper.com/oldfile. I will add the vector `key_variables` to the code above but the merge still doesn't work. The variable I want is `DInflamatoriaArticular` from the `old_data`

Comment: Can you please add the output of `dput(data1)` and `dput(old_data)` for your example instead of linking external resources?

Comment: I've added the output you asked. The links corresponds to the files. Thank you!

Comment: I realized that the dates are on different formats. That should be the reason why the files don't merge.

Comment: Yes, you can see it with `unique(data1[[key_variables[2]]]) %in% unique(old_data[[key_variables[2]]])`. That was why I asked if it is `TRUE` for all `key_variables`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already mentioned in the comments the time formats of both tables differ.
Here is a possibilty to align them:

```
library(data.table)

key_variables <-
  c(
    "sex",
    "birthdate",
    "sint",
    "cons",
    "diag",
    "concelho",
    "Serologia",
    "alcohol",
    "end",
    "micro"
  )

data1 <-
  structure(
    list(
      sex = c("Masculino", "Masculino", "Masculino"),
      birthdate = c("4/23/1952", "11/26/1964", "01/08/1965"),
      sint = c("01/01/2014",
               "09/01/2010", "01/01/2008"),
      cons = c("02/10/2014", "12/01/2010",
               "1/29/2008"),
      diag = c("02/10/2014", "12/03/2010", "02/03/2008"),
      concelho = c("vila velha de ródão", "vila velha de ródão",
                   "vila velha de ródão"),
      Serologia = c("Não", "Não", "Não"),
      alcohol = c("Sim", "Não", "Sim"),
      end = c("11/03/2014",
              "10/10/2011", "9/17/2008"),
      micro = c("03/11/2008", "12/03/2010",
                "02/03/2008"),
      DInflamatoriaArticular = c("Não", "Não", "Não")
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-3L),
    class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
  )

old_data <-
  structure(
    list(
      sex = c("Masculino", "Masculino", "Masculino"),
      birthdate = c("23/04/1952", "26/11/1964", "08/01/1965"),
      age = c(61L, 46L, 43L),
      concelho = c("vila velha de ródão",
                   "vila velha de ródão", "vila velha de ródão"),
      EstadoVital = c("Vivo",
                      "Vivo", "Vivo"),
      sint = c("01/01/2014", "01/09/2010", "01/01/2008"),
      cons = c("10/02/2014", "01/12/2010", "29/01/2008"),
      alcohol = c("Sim",
                  "Não", "Sim"),
      drugs = c("Não", "Não", "Não"),
      micro = c("11/03/2008",
                "03/12/2010", "03/02/2008"),
      diag = c("10/02/2014", "03/12/2010",
               "03/02/2008"),
      Serologia = c("Não", "Não", "Não"),
      end = c("03/11/2014",
              "10/10/2011", "17/09/2008"),
      Motivotermotratamento = c(
        "Tratamento Completado",
        "Tratamento Completado",
        "Tratamento Completado"
      ),
      ano = c(2014L,
              2010L, 2008L),
      region = c("Centro", "Centro", "Centro")
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, -3L),
    class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
  )

setkeyv(data1, key_variables)
setkeyv(old_data, key_variables)

data1[, c("birthdate", "sint", "cons", "diag", "end", "micro") := lapply(.SD, as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), .SDcols = c("birthdate", "sint", "cons", "diag", "end", "micro")]
old_data[, c("birthdate", "sint", "cons", "diag", "end", "micro") := lapply(.SD, as.Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"), .SDcols = c("birthdate", "sint", "cons", "diag", "end", "micro")]

dataFinal <- merge(data1, old_data, key_variables)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I've just done. Btw, I didn't lie, this was `TRUE` when I did `unique(data1[[key_variables[2]]]) %in% unique(old_data[[key_variables[2]]])`, with the different data structures. I guess with the rush I forgot to check the date formats and whether there was a match between the datasets =P silly mistake! Thank you for help!